# Get back to 'PS master' location in Sitecore powershell console after error

Tags: powershell-extensions

How to get back to master database location in sitecore powershell console when there is an exception while executing script.

We all know that default location when we open sitecore powershell console would be 'PS master' [image: Default location of sitecore PS console]

In the above snapshot when we have an exception in the console it returns to specific drive & how do we get back to master DB location from here.

Every time when i get this error i would close & open powershell console.

Any inputs on this please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `cd` command

You can switch between locations like this:

```powershell
cd c:/
Get-ChildItem

cd master:
Get-ChildItem
```